# clojureql query with sub-select

Tags: sql, clojure, clojureql

Given a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE transitions (id INT, ordering INT, item_id INT, action_id INT)
```

Is it possible to get ClojureQL to generate a query like this one:

```
SELECT a.item_id, a.action_id
  FROM transitions a
 WHERE a.ordering = (SELECT MAX(b.ordering)
                       FROM transitions b
                      WHERE b.item_id = a.item_id
                    )
```

This will return many rows, one for each item, indicating that item's latest transition.

I've been looking at using `join`, but worry I might hit this bug: https://github.com/LauJensen/clojureql/issues/114